# Easy way to get an actual image size from Image class.

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an object of Image class (System.Windows.Controls.Image) with Stretch property set to Uniform. I know the size of an Image control and of course size of source image but I'm looking for an easy way to get actual size of visible image.

It will be easier to explain by example. My Image control size is binded to the main window size and if it's size is 1920 x 1080, and size of source image is 500 x 500, I will see an image with size 1080 x 1080. Is there an easy way to get this size?

Comment: Have you tried [`ActualHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ActualWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not bind the Image control's size to the Window size. Instead, use a `Grid` as container. It automatically resizes the Image child element. Then the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties directly return the actual size of the control:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="..." SizeChanged="Image_SizeChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

Get the properties in code behind:

```
private void Image_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var image = (Image)sender;
    Trace.TraceInformation("Size = {0} x {1}", image.ActualWidth, image.ActualHeight);
}
```

Comment: I will try this, but I'm concerned because I don't need the size of Image control, I need size of visible image. Will this solution scale Image control and it's image source to fill grid?

Comment: That's exactly what the Grid does.

Comment: By writing "binded" I didn't mean that I bind Height and Width properties to main windows size. On top of a layout there is grid and Image is located inside of it with vertical and horizontal alignment set to stretch. I don't know why I get ActualHeight = ActualWidth = 0.0 after loading image. Any ideas?

Comment: How about showing the relevant parts of your XAML and code? You may edit your question.

Comment: It's not necessary, your solution works. I wrongly assumed that Image control size will fill whole grid and source image will fill only part of Image control, it appears that Image control and visible image sizes are the same, am I getting this right?. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute the scaling factor. And that's going to depend on the relationship between your image's size and the control's size.

First, you compute the horizontal and vertical scaling factors individually:

```
double hscale = (double)image.Width / imageControl.Width;
double vscale = (double)image.Height / imageControl.Height;
```

So if you multiplied the image's width by `hscale`, the result would be the control's width.

Now, since you want to maintain the aspect ratio, you need to pick the smallest of the two to be your scaling factor:

```
double scaleFactor = Math.Min(hscale, vscale);
```

And then you can compute the size of the image that will be displayed:

```
displayedWidth = image.Width * scaleFactor;
displayedHeight = image.Height * scaleFactor;
```